# how to create bat file on system start or hibernate and sleep

Tags: java, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, taskscheduler, windows-task-scheduler

Recently I finished developing a Java application using JavaFX. Now I want to automatically run the application when the system starts, restarts or hibernates. I'm using the code below.

```
REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v JApp /t REG_SZ /d "%~dp0MoodOMeter.jar"
TIMEOUT /T 100
```

Currently it works only on start and restart, but not on hibernate and sleep. Also, this works only on Windows at the moment. Is there a way to do this on Linux and OS X as well?

Comment: Task scheduler is for exactly this type of thing, as that is a GUI tool, your question is off topic here.

Comment: @Compo I haven't found anywhere solution so I post here may be some exprience person like you may help me

Comment: This site is a dedicated to helping you with your failing code issues, your question is not relevant, it is how do I use the task scheduler. I'd suggest that [Super User](https://superuser.com/qusestions/ask) would be a better place to ask, you could even search there first and see 
if questions like [this](https://superuser.com/q/321151) help.

Comment: @Compo thanks for your help

Comment: Strangely the tags of the question already point to the solution... Perhaps just give it a try rather than asking...